# Crontab, can't execute all the script

Tags: cron

I need to run daily a shell script which contains the steps of the model Weather Research Forecasting. I used cron for this. The first executable of the script (ungrib.exe) works perfect, but the second executable "metgrid.exe" it's not working at all. When I run the script in the terminal of linux works perfectly.

This is an example (summarized) of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash #SCRIPTSDIR/download_gfs.sh
./link_grib.csh /home/user/WRF/GFS/
./ungrib.exe
ln -s metgrid/METGRID.TBL.ARW ./METGRID.TBL
./metgrid.exe <- not running with crontab
```

The way that I configure my crontab is:

```
crontab -e

SHELL=/bin/sh

00 01 * * * /home/user/WRF/scripts/WRF_scripts.sh
```

Any idea?

Comment: Read your /var/log/syslog for cron actions --and errors-- at that time.

Comment: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: That means there was an error. Are you familiar with the cron concept of *redirecting* output to a file? That way you can read the error message. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52330/ for instructions.

Comment: Now I'm trying something like this: `00 01 * * * /home/user/WRF/scripts/WRF_scripts.sh  >> /home/user/log/file.txt 2>&1` plus `tail -f /home/user/log/file.txt` Let's see

Comment: Adding `&` suffix on `./ungrib.exe` will put it to background, then your script will carry on with the rest of the line.

Comment: `bash #SCRIPTSDIR/download_gfs.sh`? Is that `#` intentional? It'll start a comment

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was a mistake

Comment: Finally, I get it. I will put the answer later, I had to add some var to crontab envs

Answer (score 0):

I added in my crontab the full path of libraries related with the execution of WRF.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```